# How concatenate a string and a const char?

Tags: c++, string

I need to put "hello world" in c.
How can I do this ?

```
string a = "hello ";
const char *b = "world";

const char *C;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
string a = "hello ";
const char *b = "world";
a += b;
const char *C = a.c_str();
```

or without modifying `a`:

```
string a = "hello ";
const char *b = "world";
string c = a + b;
const char *C = c.c_str();
```

Little edit, to match amount of information given by *111111*.

When you already have `string`s (or `const char *`s, but I recommend casting the latter to the former), you can just "sum" them up to form longer string. But, if you want to append something more than just string you already have, you can use `stringstream` and it's `operator<<`, which works exactly as `cout`'s one, but doesn't print the text to standard output (i.e. console), but to it's internal buffer and you can use it's `.str()` method to get `std::string` from it.

`std::string::c_str()` function returns pointer to `const char` buffer (i.e. `const char *`) of string contained within it, that is null-terminated. You can then use it as any other `const char *` variable.

Comment: Better way would be to `const char *C = (a + b).c_str();`. It doesn't modify `string a`.

Comment: `(a + b).c_str()` will leave `C` pointing at invalid memory, as `+` creates a temporary `string` that will go out of scope and be destructed when the statement is finished. This is fine when passing `(a + b).c_str()` to a function parameter, but not when assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, good catch - I just mindlessly incorporated that comment into the answer.

Answer (score 10):

if you just need to concatenate then use the `operator +` and `operator +=` functions

```
 #include <string>
 ///...
 std::string str="foo";
 std::string str2=str+" bar";
 str+="bar";
```

However if you have a lot of conacatenation to do then you can use a string stream

```
#include <sstream>
//...
std::string str1="hello";
std::stringstream ss;
ss << str1 << "foo" << ' ' << "bar" << 1234;
std::string str=ss.str();
```

EDIT: you can then pass the string to a C function taking a `const char *` with `c_str()`.

```
my_c_func(str1.c_str());
```

and If the C func takes a non const char * or require ownership you can do the following

```
char *cp=std::malloc(str1.size()+1);
std::copy(str1.begin(), str2.end(), cp);
cp[str1.size()]='\0';
```

Comment: You failed to see "...put [...] in C" part of question.

Comment: @Griwes I have added a bit more